# what is the Jacobian for transformation from complex coordinate to real coordinate?

Tags: complex-analysis, linear-transformations, complex-integration, several-complex-variables

I'm trying to figure out what is the Jacobian when you do this simple transformation:

$dzdz^* \rightarrow dxdy$

where $z=x+iy$ and $z^*=x-iy$.

Follow the formula we have 
$$J(x,y)=
\begin{vmatrix}
\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} \\
\frac{\partial z^*}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial z^*}{\partial y}
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & i \\
1 & -i
\end{vmatrix}=-2i
$$
So $dzdz^* =|J(x,y)| dxdy=2dxdy$. However, this is not what is used in literatures where they either use

$dzdz^* = dxdy$

or

$dzdz^* =2i dxdy$.

So is there a definite answer for this seemingly simple question? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As differential forms:
\begin{align}
dz \wedge d\bar z &= (dx + i\,dy)\wedge (dx-i\,dy) \\
&= dx \wedge dx - i\, dx\wedge dy + i\,dy \wedge dx + dy \wedge dy \\
&= -2i\,dx \wedge dy
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not quite familiar with differential forms. How is it related to the area element dxdy?